# Which Object Oriented design is a better pick when one subclass calls another?

Tags: java, design-patterns

In my scenario, we offer multiple plans to customers. (planA, planB, planC etc.) planA is lower than planB and planB is lower than planC. A customer can move from lower plan to higher plan but not vice-versa. If a customer is on planA and wants to 'activate' planB, then planA must be cancelled. Essentially, a plan can be '**activated**' and '**deactivated**'. I had 2 designs in mind.

```
interface Plan {
   activate();
   deactivate();
}
```

This interface will be inherited by each plans' (planA, planB, planC, etc). The activate method would be inherited and look something like this:

```
activate() {
   Plan planToCancel = getLowerGradePlanToCancel()
   planToCancel.cancel();
   // perform business logic to activate plan.
}
```

**Option B** is something similar to strategy pattern: I have 2 interfaces:

```
interface Activate {
  activate();
}

interface Deactivate {
  deactivate()
}
```

Each of the plans will inherit those interfaces. Then my business logic would look something like this:

```
activatePlan(planName, planToDeactivate) {
  Activate activate = Factory.getActivateInstanceForPlan(planName);
  DeActivate dectivate = Factory.getActivateInstanceForPlan(planToDeactivate);
  deactivate.deactivate();
  activate.activate();  
}
```

Of the two designs which one is more appropriate (Object Oriented) and why ? The only thing in code that is likely to change is more plans will be added in future.

Comment: Doesn't this need to be done for a specific customer?

Comment: Think about a modified `LinkedList<Plan>` with `Plan` is your interface of your first option. Override your `next()` and `previous()` methods.

Comment: Another solution is one `Plan` object where each of `A`, `B`, and `C` is a different [State](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state) which the `Plan` can be in.

Comment: I think you're mixing up the Plan and the Subscription to a Plan. And how are you modeling the Customer? Anyhow there are far too many possible answers; this is a very opinion-based question as it is currently written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 plans. Plan C can't go higher and similarly plan A can't go lower. Plan B can do both operations. Use one interface and put activate and deactivate methods there. You already mentioned that on option A. Use template pattern there to give an opportunity to change their behaviours for your plans. This will be appropriate if you will add another plans later on. This will help you a lot when you add another plans.

If you will have only three plans, then second option is more appropriate. Since you have only 3 plans and only one of them using activate and deactivate together, then you don't need to implement both of the methods, interfaces. This will decrease the dependencies of your code.

Pick the best choice for your case.

Answer (score 1):

I have a different approach in mind where you have a class that manages all the plans, while plan interface is encapsulated and only reveals the necessary of its API.
I think this approach will have minimal code modification for each added Plan, moreover, it can prevent user from making mistakes (e.g. downgrading a plan).

The essential interfaces:

```
interface Plan {
    public Plan next();
    public boolean isActivated();
    // for debug purposes
    public String planDescription();
}

interface PlansManager {
        public Plan nextPlan(Plan current);
}
```

The basic idea is to have some SemiConcretePlan class which implements the static (mutual) behaviour in all plans, the public API is next & isActivated while activate and cancel methods private (you don't want the user to cancel a plan without switching to the next or to activated a cancelled one be keeping a previous Plan pointer on it) and only the PlansManager or the Plan itself will handle the activation and cancellation, PlansManager activates the first plan and returns it and next method uses PlansManager to get the next and only the SemiConcertePlan activate the current and cancels the previous Plan.

Here the SemiConcertePlan:

```
abstract class SemiConcretePlan implements Plan {
    private PlansManager m_plansManager;
    private boolean m_isActivated;
    private int m_id;
    private static int s_idGenerator = 0, s_firstActivatedId = 1;

    public SemiConcretePlan(PlansManager plansManager){
        m_plansManager = plansManager;
        m_id = generateId();
        m_isActivated = (m_id == s_firstActivatedId);
    }

    private int generateId() {
        return ++s_idGenerator;
    }

    private void activatePlan() { 
        this.m_isActivated = true; 
    }

    private void cancelPlan() { 
        this.m_isActivated = false; 
    }

    public boolean isActivated() { 
        return this.m_isActivated; 
    }

    public Plan next() {
        this.cancelPlan();
        SemiConcretePlan nextPlan = (SemiConcretePlan) m_plansManager.nextPlan(this);
        nextPlan.activatePlan();

        return nextPlan;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other)
                return true;
        if (other == null || !(other instanceof SemiConcretePlan) || this.hashCode() != other.hashCode())
                return false;
        SemiConcretePlan otherPlan = ((SemiConcretePlan) other);
        if (m_id != ((SemiConcretePlan) otherPlan).m_id)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public abstract int hashCode();
    public abstract String planDescription();
}
```

planDescription method is an example of dynamic method, hashCode is needed for class PlansManager to hash plans in map which map current plan to higher (next) plan.

Here is the AscedingPlansManager class:

```
class AscedingPlansManager implements PlansManager{
    private List<Plan> m_plansList;
    private Map<Plan, Plan> m_planToHigherPlanMapping;

    public AscedingPlansManager() {
        m_plansList = new LinkedList();
        m_planToHigherPlanMapping = new HashMap();
        Plan[] plans = {
                new PlanA(this),
                new PlanB(this),
                new PlanC(this),
                new PlanD(this)
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < plans.length - 1; ++i) {
            m_plansList.add(plans[i]);
            m_planToHigherPlanMapping.put(plans[i], plans[i+1]);
        }

        m_plansList.add(plans[plans.length - 1]);
        m_planToHigherPlanMapping.put(plans[plans.length - 1], plans[plans.length - 1]);
    }

    public Plan nextPlan(Plan current) {
        return m_planToHigherPlanMapping.getOrDefault(current, null);
    }

    private void activatePlan(Plan plan) {
        try {
            Method privateActivateMethod = SemiConcretePlan.class.getDeclaredMethod("activatePlan");
            privateActivateMethod.setAccessible(true);
            privateActivateMethod.invoke(plan);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void cancelAll() {
        for(Plan plan: m_plansList)
            try {
                Method privateActivateMethod = SemiConcretePlan.class.getDeclaredMethod("cancelPlan");
                privateActivateMethod.setAccessible(true);
                privateActivateMethod.invoke(plan);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public Plan firstPlan() {
        Plan first = m_plansList.get(0);
        this.activatePlan(first);

        return first;
    }

    public boolean[] plansToActivationState() {
        boolean[] ret = new boolean[m_plansList.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for(Plan plan: m_plansList)
            ret[index++] = plan.isActivated();

        return ret;
    }
}
```

I know that this is huge code, but I think it will make add plans easy, you will only need to change the hashCode method, the sequence of the plans can be changed in the constructor of AscedingPlansManager or creating a different manger class from scratch.

Here is the full code, you can see how little changes I needed to do for class PlanD:

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

```
interface Plan {
    public Plan next();
    public boolean isActivated();
    // for debug purposes
    public String planDescription();
}

interface PlansManager {
        public Plan nextPlan(Plan current);
}

abstract class SemiConcretePlan implements Plan {
    private PlansManager m_plansManager;
    private boolean m_isActivated;
    private int m_id;
    private static int s_idGenerator = 0, s_firstActivatedId = 1;

    public SemiConcretePlan(PlansManager plansManager){
        m_plansManager = plansManager;
        m_id = generateId();
        m_isActivated = (m_id == s_firstActivatedId);
    }

    private int generateId() {
        return ++s_idGenerator;
    }

    private void activatePlan() { 
        this.m_isActivated = true; 
    }

    private void cancelPlan() { 
        this.m_isActivated = false; 
    }

    public boolean isActivated() { 
        return this.m_isActivated; 
    }

    public Plan next() {
        this.cancelPlan();
        SemiConcretePlan nextPlan = (SemiConcretePlan) m_plansManager.nextPlan(this);
        nextPlan.activatePlan();

        return nextPlan;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other)
                return true;
        if (other == null || !(other instanceof SemiConcretePlan) || this.hashCode() != other.hashCode())
                return false;
        SemiConcretePlan otherPlan = ((SemiConcretePlan) other);
        if (m_id != ((SemiConcretePlan) otherPlan).m_id)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public abstract int hashCode();
    public abstract String planDescription();
}

class AscedingPlansManager implements PlansManager{
    private List<Plan> m_plansList;
    private Map<Plan, Plan> m_planToHigherPlanMapping;

    public AscedingPlansManager() {
        m_plansList = new LinkedList();
        m_planToHigherPlanMapping = new HashMap();
        Plan[] plans = {
                new PlanA(this),
                new PlanB(this),
                new PlanC(this),
                new PlanD(this)
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < plans.length - 1; ++i) {
            m_plansList.add(plans[i]);
            m_planToHigherPlanMapping.put(plans[i], plans[i+1]);
        }

        m_plansList.add(plans[plans.length - 1]);
        m_planToHigherPlanMapping.put(plans[plans.length - 1], plans[plans.length - 1]);
    }

    public Plan nextPlan(Plan current) {
        return m_planToHigherPlanMapping.getOrDefault(current, null);
    }

    private void activatePlan(Plan plan) {
        try {
            Method privateActivateMethod = SemiConcretePlan.class.getDeclaredMethod("activatePlan");
            privateActivateMethod.setAccessible(true);
            privateActivateMethod.invoke(plan);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void cancelAll() {
        for(Plan plan: m_plansList)
            try {
                Method privateActivateMethod = SemiConcretePlan.class.getDeclaredMethod("cancelPlan");
                privateActivateMethod.setAccessible(true);
                privateActivateMethod.invoke(plan);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public Plan firstPlan() {
        Plan first = m_plansList.get(0);
        this.activatePlan(first);

        return first;
    }

    public boolean[] plansToActivationState() {
        boolean[] ret = new boolean[m_plansList.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for(Plan plan: m_plansList)
            ret[index++] = plan.isActivated();

        return ret;
    }
}

class PlanA extends SemiConcretePlan {
    public PlanA(PlansManager plansManager) { 
        super(plansManager);
    }

    public int hashCode() { 
        return 1; 
    }

    public String planDescription() { 
        return "This is PlanA"; 
    }
}

class PlanB extends SemiConcretePlan {
    public PlanB(PlansManager plansManager) {
        super(plansManager);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 2;
    }

    public String planDescription() {
        return "This is PlanB";
    }
}

class PlanC extends SemiConcretePlan {
    public PlanC(PlansManager plansManager) {
        super(plansManager);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 3;
    }

    public String planDescription() {
        return "This is PlanC";
    }
}

class PlanD extends SemiConcretePlan {
    public PlanD(PlansManager plansManager) {
        super(plansManager);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 4;
    }

    public String planDescription() {
        return "This is PlanD";
    }
}


public class Main{
         public static void main(String []args){
                AscedingPlansManager ascedingPlansManager = new AscedingPlansManager();
                Plan currentPlan = ascedingPlansManager.firstPlan();

                int i = 0, maxIterations = 5;
                while((++i) <= maxIterations) {
                    System.out.println(currentPlan.planDescription());
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ascedingPlansManager.plansToActivationState()));
                    currentPlan = currentPlan.next();
                }

                ascedingPlansManager.cancelAll();
                System.out.println("After canceling all plans");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ascedingPlansManager.plansToActivationState()));
         }
}
```

I still not sure of my implementation, I usually access private method in c++ with friend modifier, if you want to discuss anything feel free to do so.